# Drawing a point over an ImageView in Android (using Xamarin)

Tags: c#, android, bitmap, xamarin.android, imageview

I am building an Android app using Xamarin and I need to be able to place some points over a map. The said map is an image displayed using an ImageView (adding it from xml directly).
I tried making a Bitmap and Canvas and it displays a black square with a red point (as wanted), but the actual map disappears. This is my code:

```
[Activity(Label = "Map")]
public class Map : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Map);

        ImageView map = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView1);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(500, 500, Bitmap.Config.Rgb565);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.SetARGB(255, 255, 0, 0);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

        //Draw the image bitmap into the canvas
        canvas.DrawBitmap(bitmap, 5, 5, paint);

        //Draw everything you want into the canvas
        canvas.DrawCircle(50, 50, 10, paint);

        //Attach the canvas to the ImageView
        map.SetImageDrawable((new BitmapDrawable(bitmap)));

        Button item = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1); //Declare item button
        item.Click += delegate
        {
            StartActivity(typeof(Item));
        };
    }
}
```

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

> I tried making a Bitmap and Canvas and it displays a black square with a red point (as wanted), but the actual map disappears.

By `map.SetImageDrawable((new BitmapDrawable(bitmap)));` you are replacing the map with your created `bitmap`.

As a quick fix, you can set the map image as the background of your layout instead of a source of the `ImageView`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/yourMapImage"
    tools:context="com.example.winffee.scrollviewdemo.MainActivity">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgMap"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```